# Is it possible remove fields on top, of tables written in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I wonder if you can hide, or even takeoff the upper fields (show 'n' tikets / Search)? I'm trying, but whenever I change the component, the footer also disappears.

[image]

Below I am pasting the code excerpt from where the call grid. And yes, I am using plugin.

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-white">
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="example" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <div>Apelido do Equipamento</div>
                                <div><input id="input-Default" class="form-control" type="text"/></div>
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                <div>Categoria<br></div>
                                <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                                <select class="form-control m-b-sm">
                                <option value="Selecione">Selecione</option>
                                <option value="Cardio">Cardio</option>
                                <option value="forca">Força</option>
                                <option value="Funcional">Funcional</option>
                                <option value="Ginastica">Ginástica</option>
                                <option value="Aquatica">Aquática</option>
                                <option value="Informatica">Informática</option>
                                <option value="Eletronicas">Eletrônicas</option>
                                <option value="Outras">Outras</option>
                            </select></div></th>

                            <th><div>Equipamento</div><div style="margin-bottom: 15px"><select>
                                <option value="Selecione">Selecione</option>
                                <option value="Esteira">Esteira</option>
                                <option value="Escada">Escada</option>
                                <option value="Supino">Supino</option>
                                <option value="Bola">Bola</option>
                            </select></div></th>

                            <th><div style="margin-bottom: 10px">Dt. Entrada</div>
                            <div style="background-color: #f1f1f1; margin-top: 5px;">
                            <input style="background-color: #f1f1f1; width: 135px;" placeholder="De" type="search"/>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            <div style="background-color: #f1f1f1; margin-top: 5px;">
                            <input style="background-color: #f1f1f1;
                             width: 135px;" placeholder="Até" type="search"/>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div></th>

                            <th><div style="margin-bottom: 10px">Próxima Manutenção</div>
                            <div style="background-color: #f1f1f1; margin-top: 5px;">
                            <input style="background-color: #f1f1f1; width: 135px;" placeholder="De" type="search"/>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            <div style="background-color: #f1f1f1; margin-top: 5px;">
                            <input style="background-color: #f1f1f1;
                             width: 135px;" placeholder="Até" type="search"/>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div></th>

                            <th><div style="margin-bottom: 25px">Status</div><div></div><div style="margin-bottom: 15px"><select>
                                <option value="Selecione">Selecione</option>
                                <option value="Em funcionamento">Em funcionamento</option>
                                <option value="Em Manutenção">Em Manutenção</option>
                                <option value="Externo">Externo</option>
                                <option value="Vendido">Vendido</option>
                            </select></div></th>

                            <th>
                                <div></div>
                                <div style="margin-top: 5px"><img alt="" style="width: 80px" src="assets/images/BotaoFiltrar.png">
                                </div>
                                <div><img alt="" style="width: 80px" src="assets/images/BotaoLimpar.png">
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>N°. Chamado</th>
                            <th>Motivo</th>
                            <th>Área</th>
                            <th>Equipamento</th>
                            <th>Dt. Abertura</th>
                            <th>Dt. Previsão</th>
                            <th>Dt. Conclusão</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>N°. Chamado</th>
                            <th>Motivo</th>
                            <th>Área</th>
                            <th>Equipamento</th>
                            <th>Dt. Abertura</th>
                            <th>Dt. Previsão</th>
                            <th>Dt. Conclusão</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000001</td>
                            <td>Esteira Quebrada</td>
                            <td>Aeróbica</td>
                            <td>EST000001</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>10/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-warning">Em espera</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000002</td>
                            <td>Esteira Quebrada</td>
                            <td>Aeróbica</td>
                            <td>EST000004</td>
                            <td>01/04/2015</td>
                            <td>30/04/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-warning">Em espera</span></td>
                        </tr>                                            
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000003</td>
                            <td>Bicicleta Quebrada</td>
                            <td>Aeróbica</td>
                            <td>BIS000020</td>
                            <td>07/07/2015</td>
                            <td>01/08/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-warning">Em espera</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000002</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Toilet</td>
                            <td>Musculação</td>
                            <td>VST000001</td>
                            <td>05/09/2015</td>
                            <td>05/09/2015</td>
                            <td>05/09/2015</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-success">Concluído</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000003</td>
                            <td>Ergométrica</td>
                            <td>Aeróbica</td>
                            <td>BCL000010</td>
                            <td>02/09/2015</td>
                            <td>10/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-warning">Em Andamento</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>0000000004</td>
                            <td>Limpeza de Caixa D'Agua</td>
                            <td>Predial</td>
                            <td>CXA0000001</td>
                            <td>01/09/2015</td>
                            <td>04/09/2015</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-danger">Atrasado</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                   </table>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- Row -->
```

Comment: Yes you can, show us your HTML code, please.

Comment: Are you using some data table plugin ? if you do, then which one ?

Comment: tks a lot. I updated post.

Comment: Thanks for the HTML, now can you answer the @GabyakaG.Petrioli question ? because `upper fields (show 'n' tikets / Search)` that you want to remove are added by some plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming by your code and screenshot that you are using the https://datatables.net plugin.

That plugin supports a multitude of options (*see https://datatables.net/reference/option/*)

The two options relevant to your question are

- `searching` (*ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching*)
- and `lengthChange` (*ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange*)

You should be able to disable those when initializing the plugin

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "searching": false,
  "lengthChange": false
} );
```

or by adding the relevant attributes on the table

```
<table id="example" data-searching="false" data-length-change="false" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;">
```